# Crowd funding Backer theme with Ignitiondeck framework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I hope to use Backer theme with their in built Ignitiondeck framework enterprise. Are there any alternatives for    [Ignitiondeck framework](http://ignitiondeck.com/id/ignitiondeck-pricing/?utm_source=licensepage&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=freemium)  Because this enterprise version is too much cost.

1. I want to know is this enterprise plugin works properly as they say?
2. What are the alternatives or free plugins works with backer theme?
3. Are there any crowdfunding themes which suite for this rather than backer theme and Ignitiondeck?

Best regards,

Lanka

Answer (score 0):

Is it WordPress theme building framework ?  Ignitiondeck framework